# Github Action JSON input is having quotes stripped when writing to file

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have an actions workflow that takes in file contents as an input and needs to write it to a file

The input is expected to be a simple JSON

```json
{"A":"1","B":"2"}
```

and then I'm running `echo "${{ github.event.inputs.file_contents}}" > temp_file`, but that's stripping out the spaces, so the contents of `temp_file` end up being

```
{A:1,B:2}
```

I'm wondering how I could get this file written from the variable contents exactly - I'm thinking a good approach could be somehow replacing the quotes with some other character before the `echo` call and then replacing them back after, or writing the file some other way.

I do have control over the file creation, and it doesn't need to be plaintext JSON, so in the mean time I'm going to Base64 encode it to get around the quotes

To reproduce you can run this and pass in some JSON

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      file_contents:
        description: 'File contents'
        required: true

jobs:
  write-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Write file
        run: |
          echo "${{ github.event.inputs.file_contents}}" > temp_file
          cat temp_file
```

Comment: Would passing the JSON via an environment variable work? See ["How to safely write JSON output to a file in a GitHub workflow?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204020/how-to-safely-write-json-output-to-a-file-in-a-github-workflow)

Comment: Pass as env variable and `echo "$DATA" > file`.